# Remove all vim 'hi link' definitions

Tags: vim, syntax, colors, highlighting

vim 8.0's `:h :hi-link` indicates `:hi link {from-group} NONE` will remove a `hi-link` for one group. How can I remove all `hi-link` definitions? `hi clear`, `syn clear`, and `syn off` do not clear `hi-link`s.

Answer (score -2):

Why would you need that? I don't see a use case for resetting *all* links; that's why it hasn't been implemented.

Links are commonly used to customize syntax highlighting:

> Most *filetypes* (like `python`) in Vim come with a syntax that defines highlight groups (see them via `:highlight`). These particular groups (e.g. `pythonFunction`) are then *linked* to a set of default groups (`:help highlight-groups`, e.g. `Identifier`). A *colorscheme* then provides combinations of foreground / background color and/or formatting like bold and italic (separately for terminals, color terminals, and/or GVIM) for the default groups.
>
> highlight group → default group → color + style
>   `pythonFunction` → `Identifier` → `term=underline ctermfg=3 guifg=DarkCyan`

This usually is a static affair, i.e. once done in your `~/.vimrc`. There's usually no need to reconfigure this on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. This doesn't at all answer OP's question.

Comment: @dsifford: It does: This isn't needed, so it's not (easily) possible. Unfortunately, OP didn't mention a concrete use case, so I guess there is none.

Comment: The salient use-case for this is for theme maintainers. If a maintainer were to create custom base-groups for their theme and then link syntax groups to that custom base group, there currently exists no way to remove the links to those base groups  if the user were to switch themes, rendering all linked subgroups out of scope. A few themes that do this from the top of my head are Gruvbox and Dracula, but there are several other highly popular themes out there that do it as well.

Comment: @Ingo when posting an answer, you're expected to actually answer the OP's question rather than second guess what he's attempting to do. Ask context clarification questions in a comment. Thank you.